Why won't the action value set in the state?
Given the following state
export const initialState: State = {
    filters: {
        typeahead: [],
    },
    cases: [] as CaseData[],
    recordsReview: {} as DCMedicalRecordsReview,
    caseMetrics: {
        filter: {
            payer: '',
            lob: ''
        },
        providers: [],
        patients: []
    }
}

I am trying to pass a single string of data into the reducer and set it in the state
        on(CasesActions.setPayerFilter, (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            caseMetrics: {
                ...state.caseMetrics,
                filter: {
                    ...state.caseMetrics.filter,
                    payer: action.payer
                }
            }
        })),

This is done using the following action
'Set Payer Filter' : props<{ payer: string}>()
When I attempt to display or log the set state, I receive an undefined. I am attempting to retrieve the information from the following selector:
export const selecselectCaseMetricsFilterPayerCase = createSelector(
    casesFeature.selectCaseMetrics,
    (metrics) => metrics.filter.payer
)

Why is this coming up undefined?

Updates from Comments:
The action is being called from the filter change:
<div class="col">
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="payer_id" ngModel (ngModelChange)="onPayerFilterChange($event)">
        <option value="">--Payer--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let payer of payerFilters$()" [value]="payer">{{payer}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

on update the action is called:
  onPayerFilterChange(payer: any) {
    this.store.dispatch(CasesActions.setPayerFilter(payer))
  }

the payload being sent is a simple string {payer: string}

please share more code, like casesFeature.selectCaseMetrics and how you are calling CasesActions.setPayerFilter

What is casesFeature.selectCaseMetrics in the selector function? What payload value are you passing to the dispatched CasesActions.setPayerFilter action? Where/how is this selecselectCaseMetricsFilterPayerCase selector function being called/used? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

@NarenMurali  these are done, hopefully the comments are substantial

@DrewReese hopefully this is satisfactory, there's not really much of an example to reproduce, I'm sending a string. There is no additional service call to an api or anything.

In onPayerFilterChange payer is typed as any. What is the value here at this point? And what about the selector code and usage?

@MarkHill Could you try this.store.dispatch(CasesActions.setPayerFilter({ payer }))

Since you have mentioned that the type should be {payer: string}, then we can emit an object with the property name as payer, then it should work.
onPayerFilterChange(payer: any) {
  this.store.dispatch(CasesActions.setPayerFilter({ payer }))
}

